# How to change longhand date+time to shorthand, operable Datetime in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to run an operand on 2 dataframe columns, to determine the DTE (day's to expiration) by subtracting expiry column from current date column.  I've tried converting the columns into floats, or integers, or pd.to_datetime() but can't get the operand to work, and can't get the dates to convert to '8-21-2018' format.

I've tried the following:

```
     opt_chain['Expiry'] = pd.to_datetime(opt_chain['Expiry']) 
     opt_chain.head()
     #AND/OR
`.   mkt_calls['DTE'] = [mkt_calls['Expiry'] - mkt_calls['Date']]
     mkt_calls.head()
```

& with float(), int(), & to_datetime()

Please advise, I've provided screenshot of the dataframe, it's a mess.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCsAm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Both objects need to be date time, and to put into shorthand use:

'''

```
opt_chain['Expiry'] = pd.to_datetime(opt_chain['Expiry'],format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.floor('d')

opt_chain['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(mkt_calls['Date'],format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.floor('d')
opt_chain['DTE'] = opt_chain.Expiry - opt_chain.Date
```

'''

the dt.floor('d') removes the time attribute... %Y is full year format.

Just in case anyone else was curious !

-ZMazz